# Can I run .NET objects on Mono that have a dependency on COM components?

Tags: linux, com, mono, dcom

We have some .NET types on Windows that have dependencies on some COM components.

If we were to switch to Mono, what options would we have for still using the functionality in these COM components?

The most obvious thing that springs to mind is DCOM.  Is this feasible?  Any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mono - yes (as long as you stay on Windows). On Linux - probably not, as you won't have a Linux implementation of those COM objects.